# PHP - Static methods in call_user_func_array()

Tags: php

I have a MVC Project and I have used call_user_func_array function to pass the arguments to the specific method in the controller, but the main problem here is that the method must be static, and someTimes I do really need to use $this inside that static method which is the method of the controller :/
Here's that message which explain everything: ***Deprecated: Non-static method home::index() should not be called statically in [Location..]***

My Question here is: is there any other way to solve that problem and work with the regular methods .. !
-- Maybe other function instead of the call_user_func_array or anything else :)) -> Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can all methods non-statically via an array as shown in the example [in the manual for `call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
<?php

$parameters = ['one', 'two'];
$class = new className;
call_user_func_array([$class, 'method'], $parameters);

class className
{
     public function method($one, $two)
....
```

Comment: I have already done this, that's exactly what i did .. anyway just for more infos, instead of $class i put $controller which it has the same name of the class and everyting eles is identical.

Comment: You need to pass an object as `$controller` not a string, did you instantiate the object first?

Comment: Yes sure, i have instantiated the class in the controller and pass it as an argument in the first element array in the first arg in the func

Comment: If it was identical to the example it wouldn't be called statically, so there must be something else in your code calling a method statically because using `[$class, 'method']` calls it on the instantiated object exactly the same as if you'd called `$class->method()`

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake from me .. i diden't instantiated the class, Damn .. I was stucking like 2 days ago in this obstacle Huh OMG . Anyway thanks bro! 

Comment: Sorry but how could i close the question! And mark your answer !

Comment: I think you need more reputation to mark it and you don’t close answers 